# Error message: ´)´expected, and "not a statement" ´;´expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am totally new to programming. I´m reading some tutorials on the internet, and also Barry Burds "Java for dummies" while trying to learn programming Java. I have tried all variations I could think of without success. 
In one exercise I am supposed to make the following program to print a message in a "messageDialogBox" which should contain the numbers wrote in by the user of the program. Unfortunately I get thhe following error message when trying to compile: Can somebody please help me get the code to work? What is wrong with the code?

```
5 errors
Addition2.java:24: ')' expected
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, firstnumber "+" secondnumber
                                                      ^
Addition2.java:25: not a statement
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
      ^
Addition2.java:25: ';' expected
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
           ^
Addition2.java:25: not a statement
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                   ^
Addition2.java:25: ';' expected
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
```

The code is the following:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Addition2
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      String firstnumberstring;
      String secondnumberstring;

      int firstnumber;
      int secondnumber;
      int sum;

      firstnumberstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 
            "Write first number" );
      secondnumberstring =
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Write second number" );

      firstnumber = Integer.parseInt( firstnumberstring );
      secondnumber = Integer.parseInt( secondnumberstring );

      sum = firstnumber + secondnumber;

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, firstnumber "+" secondnumber
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings using the string cat operator: +

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, firstnumber  + "+" + secondnumber + " = " + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
```

Btw; it's considered a good thing to declare variables where they are assigned for the first time - and not sticking to the old c- requirement (with ancient roots) that all variables must be declared before the actual code.

```
String firstnumberstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 
        "Write first number" );
```

It helps a little when trying to figure out where a variable is used.
It's particulary good when a variable is used only in a specific scope; ( inside curly brackets)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `showMessageDialog` is intended to present the result of the addition, this line

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstnumber "+" secondnumber
      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

should probably read something like

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstnumber + "+" + secondnumber + "=" +
                                                ^     ^              ^^^^^^^

      + sum, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

(Just putting strings and numbers beside each other doesn't concatenate them. You'll have to put a `+` in between!)

Also, note that `5 + 3 + " hello"` yields `"8 hello"`. To produce `53 hello`, you'd have to do for instance `"" + 5 + 3 + " hello"`.

---

You could also use for instance [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in which case the code would look like

```
String msg = String.format("%d + %d = %d", firstnumber, secondnumber, sum);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thank you som much! I was 3 + signs short. Making it + "+" did the trick! Again Thank you som much!

Comment: Be sure to upvote all helpful answers and accept the answer that answered your question / solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
firstnumber "+" secondnumber
```

It's not clear what you mean here. Did you actually want an arithmetic sum? If so, you shouldn't have quotes around the `+` operator:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstnumber + secondnumber + sum,
    "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
```

If you *actually* meant to use string concatenation and include "+" in the string, you need to use something like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstnumber + "+" + secondnumber + "=" + sum,
    "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
```

Looking at a bit like this:

```
+ "+" +
```

the first and third `+` signs here are the string concatenation operator. The middle one is within a string literal.